# Why won't APKTool execute?

Tags: terminal, apk, apktool

I was using APKTool and have been doing a lot of trials, using all the versions of APKTool. However, upon to my dismay, it won't work. Whenever I use it it will just be:

```
-bash: ./apktool: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what to do, as I tried using "./" as what websites are telling me, but still it just gives me this.

What should I do to fix this error. Thanks :)

**-----Edit (December 23, 2015)-------**

I have found the solution to the problem and it was just a redownload of APKTool itself. It also helped when I gained an understanding of Terminal and the Command Line Tools. I advice you to do the same thing too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should reinstall apktool. You can find how to do it here:
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

Using "./" means that you want to run file located in current folder. Since you mentioned "bash" your apktool should be probably installed in "/usr/local/bin" so when you complete the installation do not add "./" just type "apktool" to run it.

If you want to check where apktool is installed run "which apktool"

Comment: What do you mean, run "which apktool"?

Answer (score 0):

or simply use the apktool online: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool
No installation - no hassle!